# Is totally ordered magma infinite?

Tags: abstract-algebra, order-theory, magma

It is well known that any non-trivial totally ordered group is infinite.
Is it true that any totally ordered magma with more than one element is infinite too?

My attempt to prove the statement:

Let's say a magma $M(\cdot)$ is totally ordered if it has a total order $<$ compatible with the operation:
$a < b \implies ac < bc$ and $ca < cb$ for any elements $a$, $b$, $c$ from $M$.

Applying the compatibility for any two distinct elements $a < b$ of $M$: $aa < ab < bb$;

Therefore:

1. For any two distinct elements $a$ and $b$ of $M$ the elements $aa$ and $bb$ are distinct;
2. For any two distinct elements $aa < bb$ of $M$ there is an element $ab$ such that $aa < ab < bb$;

Assuming $M$ has $n > 1$ elements $\{ m_1 ... m_n \}$;

- $M' = \{ m_1m_1, m_2m_2, ..., m_nm_n \}$ is a subset of $M$;
- All the elements $\{ m_1m_1, m_2m_2, ..., m_nm_n \}$ are distinct (from 1);
- $M = M'$ since $M'$ is a subset of $M$ with $n$ elements;

For any two consecutive elements $m_im_i < m_jm_j$ from $M$ there is an element $m_im_j$ between them (from 2);

Contradiction.

Is this correct?
Where can I read about a linear and a cyclic order on a magma?

Comment: Yes, it's correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your argument is correct but maybe a bit too long.

Suppose your totally ordered finite "magma" is $M=\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n\}$ where $a_1\lt a_2\lt\cdots\lt a_n$.

For any $c\in M$ we have $a_1c\lt
a_2c\lt\dots\lt a_nc$, whence $a_ic=a_i$. That is, $M$ satisfies the identity $xy=x$.

A similar argument shows that $M$ satisfies $xy=y$ and therefore $x=y$, that is, the "magma" is trivial.

Comment: Note that the result depends on the strict order. For the weaker definiton $ a\leq b⇒ac \leq bc$ and $a\leq b ⇒ ca \leq cb$ there is a simple counter example on the base set $\{a,b\}$ with $aa = a$ and $ab = ba = bb = b$. This definition is also used in combination with semigroups. Nevertheless, for groups both definitions are equivalent due to the inversion.

Comment: For the weaker definition there are lots of finite examples, e.g. any finite semilattice.